# Git - require merging commits from master before allowing push to branches

Tags: git

We’d like to prevent lengthy merge conflicts between development branches by requiring these branches to pull/merge from the master branch before allowing a push to the development branch (if there are any changes to the master branch).  Is this possible to enforce?

Comment: You could possibly implement a pre-receive hook which checks to see if the current tip of `master` is an ancestor of `HEAD`?

Comment: The previous comment is slightly flawed: `pre-receive` runs on the server (like the somewhat equivalent `update` hook), and `HEAD` there refers to the "default branch" that is checked out in fresh clones. In most repositories the default branch is `master`, so then comparing `master` to `HEAD` is not very useful.

Comment: @JanKrüger any comment to improve the thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, depending on how your central repository is hosted. If it's hosted at something like GitHub or GitLab.com, this will probably not be possible because these types of providers don't allow you to provide your own code to check pushes (you can configure some restrictions via their web interface but I don't think what you want is possible there).

For a self-hosted repository, you can do this in an `update` hook (see the [documentation for hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)). Here's an example that I haven't actually tested:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "refs/heads/development" -a "$(git rev-list $3..master)" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: master is not merged into development, please try again" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

This essentially checks that there's "nothing left" if you subtract the set of commits from the new state of `development` from the set of commits on `master`. If you have merged, `development` will have all of `master`'s commits so the result will be the empty set.

This is fairly simple but has a few minor drawbacks:

- If the same push also updates `master`, the check in this hook may not be aware of the new changes to `master` yet, so in that case you might get a false negative (unmerged changes but push goes through).
- If the last (and only) new thing that happened on `master` was a merge from `development`, the hook will give a false positive of sorts because `master` will have that merge commit while `development` won't. Of course we know that that's an immaterial difference between the two branches, but the simple set arithmetic in the hook doesn't understand these distinctions.

Comment: Interesting, although unfortunately we use Bitbucket to host.  I’ll have to see if it’s a possibility.  Thanks!